# How can Navigation with openStreetMap osm

Tags: navigation, mapping, move-base, ros-noetic

After I publish osm_cartography and can see the map in rviz, what do I do next to make the robot navigate through the map? Do I use move_base or some other package? If I use move_base, how can I load this map to move_base? Or if there's another package, what package would it be?

[image: osm_cartograthy map]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, welcome to Roboticks Stack Exchange! `osm_cartography` only publishes the OSRM information for visualization purposes. In that case, you would have to create some software that could translate the VisualMarkers into other message such as Lines, or RoadLines and follow them, or either use the OSRM API to ask a destination, and again, create some piece of software that splits the information from the response you received. If you want `move_base` to work with OSRM map, I don't think there's no way to create a map directly using the information from the osm_cartography

Comment: thank you for your reply
is there documentation or books to help us to make this software?
or is there other way to make navigation in road lines  ?

Comment: If you are talking about OSRM path planning I doubt that there is something public available. In the other hand, navigate using road lines is well spread and there are a few examples, normally it is done using visual resources such as a camera and some OpenCV algorithms, you could check out the Duckietown project to see an example of following a line. Then you would have to investigate all the cases and how to aboard them, and develop a controller to handle the error to keep on track as good as possible.

Comment: OK, thank you very much I will try this.

Comment: Glad to hear it, feel free to ask again if needed